# Clear item with custom name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you clear 1 item from the inventory that has a custom name? What I'm trying to do is make a torch that when you hold it, it gives you Night Vision effect but after like 400 ticks or so I want the torch to run out of fuel and clear 1 torch away from the inventory, I have the potion effects (giving and taking away) working and the testfor command but how do I clear the item? this is my code I'm trying to use `/clear @a torch 1 1 {display:{Name:"Special Torch"}}`

Comment: +1 because you tried something :) Welcome to Arqade btw.

Comment: Related: [Why is it bad practice to test for item names?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-test-for-item-names)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for clear is as following:

```
/clear [player] [item] [data] [maxCount] [dataTag]
```

Your command is as following:

```
/clear @a torch 1 1 {display:{Name:"Special Torch"}}
```

You are trying to clear (for everyone in the server) torches with a data value of 1, a max count of 1 and a name of "Special Torch".

Seeing as there are no torches with a data value of 1, try using the following:

```
/clear @a torch 0 1 {display:{Name:"Special Torch"}}
```

Comment: Thank you I thought I was using syntax incorrectly it turned out I used the wrong data

Comment: ***THIS ANSWER IS OUTDATED.*** This answer is for 1.12-. If you are playing in 1.13+, use the below answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

**The accepted answer is now outdated. Please read this answer if you are playing in 1.13+.**

## 1.13+ Update

The syntax of the clear command changed in version 1.13; the NBT data is now incorporated into the item parameter, the data value has been removed, and JSON formatting has been added to the `Name`  The updated command would now be the following:

```
/clear @a minecraft:torch{display:{Name:'{"text":"Special Torch"}'}} 1
```

You can omit the count (last parameter) to clear all items that match.