# Minecraft: How To Make Vanilla Mods With Commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When browsing Planet Minecraft, I come across Vanilla Minecraft Mods by using one command. I am interested in the idea and how to do it.

Here are two people that do this: http://www.planetminecraft.com/member/theredengineer/
http://www.planetminecraft.com/member/ijaminecraft/

These people create mods like, furniture, cars, motorcycles, campfires, and special mechanics.
Three primary devices include:
http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/minecraft-tents-and-camp-fires-with-only-2-command-blocks-camping-mod-vanilla/
http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/furniture-in-vanilla-minecraft-chairstablestvs/
http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/motorbike-vanilla-mod/

How is this achieved? How does one combine items in Minecraft to make other items? How do they create objects like furniture and motorcycles?

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about how they make the functions the mods do themselves, then that is a matter of many, many combines commands. Furniture most likely is from multiple invisible armor stands with blocks on their head. If you put 20/30/40 armorstands in the same place with different block on their head and different head/body orientations, you can *basically* make a block model without resource packs or actual mods.

Also, the way these creations work is most likely on a fill clock that is constantly powering a set of command (20 times a second) that check for you placing down a block or something, and doing stuff when that action occurs (like spawning in all those armor stands when you place down a certain spawn egg or block that creates the furniture).

But if you are talking about how they put all that stuff into one, two or three commands, then that is call a one-click command block structure spawner. These, when pasted into a command block on any world and powered, will replicate the command block structure the original creators made.

While there are many mcedit filters out there that will do this, the one that will copy the blocks in raw (not modify the structure or add anything) is [GentleGiantJGC's mcedit filter.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/2497705-mcedit-filter-selection-to-command)

If you would like to get started in making these types of things, i suggest looking through the [Gamemode 4 modules](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpa6LLAKqMWbXt5VvxCc6H4mwI-qacdGA). Gamemode 4 is a way to play MC with many of these modules installed in the world. They already have 35 modules, with things from undead players to extra hearts with heart canisters to using minecarts up and down walls. The most notable *module* is the [custom crafter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNmbESVpDmU&index=28&list=PLpa6LLAKqMWbXt5VvxCc6H4mwI-qacdGA) which is the universal way to craft special items that lots of other modules use to do their own special things and [how to create a custom crafter recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZcKFR4lEWo&index=32&list=PLpa6LLAKqMWbXt5VvxCc6H4mwI-qacdGA).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the visuals are created by carefully positioning invisible ArmorStands holding/wearing items, custom player heads, particle effects, banners, falling sand, invisible mobs, entities riding other entities, etc.

This can be done using `/summon`, `/entitydata` and or `/tp` to correctly position entities until something looks how you want it to.

There's such a huge range of variation in terms of how to make custom "mods" that I don't feel there's one specific real answer to what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot create new blocks, items or entities using command blocks.**

These features have to be declared *before Minecraft has loaded*, you have to use mods.

Comment: He isn't talking about new blocks, items, or entities. He is referring to the fact that you can use blocks in the game to make them.

Comment: @LucidiousXIV Fair point. I just saw "vanilla mods" and went with that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following links to be the ultimate use, I guarantee if it's possible and already discovered, it's in one of those.

- http://minecraftjson.com/
- http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp
- http://json.parser.online.fr/
- [Clear item with custom name?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194098/clear-item-with-custom-name)
- http://www.summon-helper.net/
- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_Tags?cookieSetup=true#Entities
- http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/mapping-and-modding-tutorials/2225178-1-8-command-block-tutorials-custom-map-mechanics
- http://www.dragnoz.net/
- http://mrgarretto.com/commandvert
- http://www.minecraftupdates.com/summon-command
- http://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/
- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block
- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Mobs
- http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/2142815-1-8-minecraft-command-generator

Comment: Could you please edit the link? Dropbox says that the file has been moved/deleted.

Comment: While these links are useful, an answer containing a link to a list of links that even broke in the past is just plain bad. I edited the links into the answer. I also removed the unnecessary chatter at the end as it did nothing to improve the answer.

Comment: Also, regarding your edit: It's very good that you reacted and updated the link. However, SE has an amazing revision history (click on "edited X ago"), so there's no need to signal edits in the text, meaning you could (and should) have simply replaced the old link with the new one. I suggest you check out the [tour] and [help] for the site if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this website: http://mrgarretto.com/cmdcombiner
You can use it to write commands, and it will create a giant command just like their vanilla mods!