# How to take away only one of multiple items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an enchanting shop, where you click a button, it takes away your sword, gives you an enchanted one. But currently, I am using /clear to take away the sword, so if someone has more swords, it takes away all of them. How do I do this? Do you have to add a number somewhere? I am not trying to take away items with custom names, just a normal diamond sword.

Comment: There is [a similar post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194098/clear-item-with-custom-name?rq=1) where you can find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `/clear` is:

```
/clear [player] [item] [data] [maxCount] [dataTag]
```

To make it only take away one sword, put maxCount as 1.