# Giving potion effect when I hold an Item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried for some time to fix my problem alone, but now i need some help ! ( 1.16.4 version )
I am making server with friends using custom items and powers related to them, in this example it's a wand of levitation.
So here's the command that I've used :

execute if entity @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stick",tag:{display:{Name:'[{"text":"WAND OF LEVITATION","color":"gold","bold":true},{"text":"","color":"gold","bold":false}]'}}}}] run effect give @s minecraft:levitation 1 3 true

This isn't showing me any error, just not applying the levitation effect. why ? Command block on Repeat-Unconditional-Always active
[image: Here is the Item]

Comment: This other problem is the only thing that I can see. Please read it carefully. [Why is it bad practice to test for item names?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-test-for-item-names)

Comment: Yup, as ExpertCoder14 said, it is not good to test for item names. Try adding custom NBT tags and test for those instead.