# How can I clear an item with custom name in Minecraft 1.16.5

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As mentioned in the title, I am looking for a command that will remove the item with the changed name from the player's inventory. I tried using:

```
/clear @p acacia_boat {{{display:{Name:'{"text":"blabla"}'}} 1
```

And nothing works. I searched the internet but didn't turn up any results, and I've found no answer anywhere when trying to do this on version 1.16.5.

Comment: does using `minecraft:acacia_boat` instead work?

Comment: yes, and doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it bad practice to test for item names?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-test-for-item-names)

Comment: Voting to reopen. This should not have been closed because it is not clear whether the asker is asking for *specifically* detecting the renamed item, or whether they're just testing for the custom name because they need *some* way of detecting their renamed item.

Comment: @pppery would like to see what you think on [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/when-should-why-is-it-bad-practice-to-test-for-item-names-not-be-used-as-a-du)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 So should it be closed as needing details?

Comment: @Joachim "Needs details or clarity" is for stuff like "I don't even know what you're talking about." It is **not** for stuff like "Okay, this makes sense, but I just need to know whether this falls under category A or B."

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I think it can be, but that's not the point here - in this case I'm just asking because you wrote "it is not clear whether the asker is asking for specifically detecting the renamed item, or whether ..", but i might be misinterpreting your comment. Hence the question :)

Comment: @Joachim It is clear what the issue is, but in order for an answer, they need to specify whether the name is *decorative* or *non-decorative*. I don't vote to close this question because, how were they supposed to know that there is a difference in the first place?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I understand and agree. But closing a question can be done purely because more information is needed, and does in no way reflect badly on the OP. It's just a heads-up, a prompt to action, and to avoid others answering a question when they actually can't.

Comment: @Joachim I have found in experience that reopening a question is actually harder than it looks, and I do believe that there are too many people out there who will vote to leave closed even after the issues are corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to state the item then add the modifier:

```
 {display:{Name:'{"text":"custom name"}'}}
```

Example:

```
/clear @a minecraft:torch{display:{Name:'{"text":"lighter"}'}}
```