# Check for named item in helmet slot not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a SCP-035 mask in Minecraft with command blocks. (since I think it would be fun and people only make NPCs)

I am trying to make the part where it checks when you put it on and then runs the rest of the commands and stuff.

I have tried copy pasting commands into my command blocks but they don't work either. I have tried looking online to see if anyone has has done an actual mask but no.

Here is my current command:

```
execute if entity @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:skeleton_skull",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"SCP-035\"}"}}}]}]
```

PS: (This is a repeating, unconditional, always active command block)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is your `run` part of the execute command? How do you know that it isn't working if it there isn't a response setted up?

Also, what error are you getting, in case you do have a `run` part? The `run` part never triggers?

Comment: It is running into a comparator, I also tried using run say hi

Comment: No errors by the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it bad practice to test for item names?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-test-for-item-names)

Answer (score 1):

The source of problem originates probably from the name of your mask given to yourself and the name criteria written in the nbt check.
There may exists discrepancies between these two which makes the tag unsuitable for nbt checks.

What I would recommend for you to do is to use the `{CustomModelData:int}` tag.

```
execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b,tag:{CustomModelData:int}}]}] at @s run yourfunction
```

Like so.

```
give @s skeleton_skull{CustomModelData:int} 1
```

Give yourself the corresponding skull.

This is bound to be correct since the tag is simply an integer, which provides added efficiency to your functions. Additionally, it is much easier for you to synchronize your functions with resource packs shall the need arise.

By the way, I am curious about what you would add into the game for the possession mask, for I am a fan of the SCP-verse as well.

Edit: Another suggestion - create a datapack for your project and bolster your efficiency exponentially

Comment: Nice! I will check if your answer works! Also, I am thinking it would like give you blindness and wither then when you die it would summon a npc (like in the videos) at your location.

Comment: Is the int an integer or is that the actual value?

Comment: int=any integer