# How to rename an item in an unduplicatable way, without commands or op?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm in need of renaming items in a way that others can't easily duplicate. These are for loot box type machines.

My server doesn't have anything plug in wise that does it. There is no Magic command. Can I use Alt codes or unicode for something that is whitespace or obfuscated?

For 1.19.4 also...

Edit:
The linked question isn't related at all actually. I have no access to json files or give commands.

I'm checking items using a Redstone item sorter... So the only real distinguishing property will be the name. That's why I need a way to be able to name it where someone else couldn't just use an anvil to rename gold nuggets (or the other items I use) to be the keys or tokens I plan on selling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it bad practice to test for item names?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-test-for-item-names)

Comment: What are you using to rename and check names? A anvil with filters or commands? If not commands, then the duplicate is more a reference than anything.

Comment: When you say "machine", do you mean redstone or commands? With commands, you can just give them an NBT tag. Even then, items can be duplicated with bugs.

Comment: Machine = Redstone... And no commands. I have no rights to commands as I'm not staff.

Answer (score 1):

If it were with commands you could just add a custom NBT tag to the loot box items. Example: `/give @s <some item> {customid:"loot_box_rare"}`

For survival no-cheats get yourself a book and quill, type some text in it maybe indicating the tier of the loot box (if you will have tiers) or that it is a loot box or put some ASCII art or nothing, but then, *sign it* and it gets an NBT tag that no other player can create without commands. Written books that are identical in terms of NBT data can stack up to 16, so make sure you use copies *of the original book* and *open each of them separately* before putting them in the sorting system or giving them out. This is because of an NBT tag called `resolved` which becomes true when a book has been opened at least once.

Comment: Hey, you missed a closing backtick and your give command is now wrong (can't edit it myself because it's less than 6 characters)