# How do I clear a specific book named "example"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried this code but I don't know what to put instead of `BookName`

```
clear @a written_book{BookName:"example"}
```

How do I clear a specific book named "example"?

Comment: Unsure if this answers your question: [Clear item with custom name?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194098/clear-item-with-custom-name)

Comment: Probably not - Written Books appear to use their own NBT format. In any event, though ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it bad practice to test for item names?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-test-for-item-names)